# Attaching Excel sheet using Java and Xpages

Tags: java, lotus-domino, xpages-ssjs

Having problems attaching an Excel spreadsheet to a notes document using java.  For more context we are using SKSpreadsheet off openNTF (which is pretty cool).

I have a handle to the spreadsheet - named book.
I create a notes doc and attach it without too much drama.
I cannot open the attachment (after it is attached) as it says it is corrupt ("Excel cannot open the file as the file format or file extension is not valid) .
The attachment has zero bytes - which can't be good.

Is there a special way to get a file off either "File Resources" or web content folder or in this case SKSpreadsheet and save it to a Notes Doc as an attachment.

Thanks in advance.

The doSave method below that I call from Javascript via an xpage.

```
public void doSave() {

ComponentBinding.getBridge("sheet").execute(new Action() {

public void doAction(ZulBridgeBase bridge) {

// get the spreadsheet
Spreadsheet ss = ((SpreadsheetRichBridge)

bridge).getSpreadsheet();

Book book = ss.getBook();

String errmsg = null;

try {

getBookService().saveBook(bookname, book);



NotesContext ctx = NotesContext.getCurrent();

Session session = ctx.getCurrentSession();

Database db = ctx.getCurrentDatabase();

Document doc = db.createDocument();

doc.replaceItemValue("Subject", "Attachment");

doc.replaceItemValue("Form", "Main");

RichTextItem body = doc.createRichTextItem("Body");

body.appendText("Here is the attachment:");

body.addNewLine(2);

**body.embedObject(EmbeddedObject.EMBED_ATTACHMENT,
null, "/" + book.getBookName(),null);**

// Save the document
doc.save(true, true);

} catch(NotesException e1) {
System.out.println(e1.id + " " + e1.text);
e1.printStackTrace();

} catch (Exception e) {
e.printStackTrace();
errmsg = e.getMessage();
}
if (errmsg != null) {
addMessage(errmsg);
} else {
addMessage("book " + bookname + " was saved");
}
}
});
}
```

Comment: Are you sure that the file you want to attach exists? To be certain that this is not the source of the error, you could raise an exception if the file doesn't exists: `if (!new File("/"+book.getBookName()).exists()) throw ...`

Comment: Additionally, the second parameter you pass to `embedObject` (class) is `null`. the documentation says that 'If you are using EMBED_OBJECTLINK or EMBED_ATTACHMENT, specify an empty string ("")'. This is unlikely to cause the problem, but you never know :)